# Qual é a diferença entre Model::lists() e Model::all()->lists() no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

No `Laravel`, temos um método que podemos listar campos de uma tabela no estilo chave valor.

Posso fazer isso de duas formas

Assim:

```
Usuario::lists('nome', 'id');
```

E Assim:

```
Usuario::all()->lists('nome', 'id');
```

O resultado disso seria:

```
 [1 => 'Wallace', 2 => 'Guilherme', 3 => 'Bigown', 4 => 'Miguel']
```

Mas, tendo em visto que existe duas maneiras de fazer isso, qual é a diferença entre as duas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, a diferença é a seguinte: Quando você invoca `lists` você faz com que apenas os campos específicos sejam especificados na query do `Orm` do laravel e os trás num `array`.

Exemplo:

```
Usuario::lists('nome', 'id');
```

É o mesmo que :

```
SELECT nome, id FROM usuarios
```

Já o caso do método `all` seguido de `lists` ocorre outra coisa.
Quando chamamos `Usuario::all()` trazemos todos os resultados existentes na tabela `usuarios` e com todos os campos selecionados.

```
SELECT * FROM usuários
```

O método `all` retornará um objeto chamado `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. Esse objeto, por sua vez, possui o método `all`. Porém internamente, ele utiliza a função chamada `array_pluck` para capturar apenas os dois itens passados, como chave e valor.

**Performance**

A diferença de performance é notável entre as duas explicações. `lists` saí ganhando tanto na execução da query como na quantidade de dados trazidos para o PHP.

Se você for apenas trazer uma lista contendo o par chave-valor do banco, você deverá usar `lists`.

Porém há casos onde, além de trazer os dados completos do usuário, por questões de necessidade de um tipo determinado, você desejaria transformar um objeto `Eloquent\Collection` em um `array`.

Nesse caso, estamos falando de um conceito da orientação a objetos chamado de Reutilização.

Um exemplo disso é precisar de trazer todos os dados do usuário para fazer uma listagem numa tabela, porém ao mesmo tempo precisar de uma listagem desses usuários em um select (aí será necessário usar `lists` nessa coleção, para não fazer outro SELECT no banco).

Vou dar um exemplo:

```
 $usuario = Usuario::all();

 // Preciso da lista de nomes e ids para passar para um "select" no html

$usuarios_lista = $usuarios->lists('nome', 'id');
```